# If each object in a system is driven by the same force,can I use conservation of linear momentum for this system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/75sd0.jpg)
The solution I have just makes an equation of conservation of linear momentum which is so easy to make and then arrives at a solution. 
There is force due to gravity on the bullet and bob system then how can the solution use conservation of linear momentum here?

Answer (score 0):

The collision between the two objects is inelastic, so you can't use conservation of energy before and after the collision. You can tell it's inelastic because in an elastic collision the objects will be moving away from eachother. After the collision you can use conservation of energy just fine (ignoring friction).

The energy is given by $$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}+mgh$$
Here $\frac{p^2}{2m}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is the kinetic energy, $h$ the height of the bob and $m$ the mass of the bob and bullet combined. It is convenient to define $h=0$ when the bob is hanging still. You then use $E(h=0)=E(h=1.8)$ to calculate the initial momentum of the bob and bullet combined. Now you can use conservation of momentum to calculate the momentum of the bullet before it hit the bob and you just divide by the mass of the bullet.

What answer do you get?

Comment: 6 for the combined one,60 for the bullet

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated I n this sort of problem you have to make an assumption about the collision between the bullet and the bob - during the collision no external forces act on the bullet and ball system.
Then for the next phase of the motion you would use the conservation of mechanical energy.

The no external force assumption might seem a little strange in that there is a tension in the string and gravitational attractive forces on the bullet and the bob which would produce impulses on the components of the system which could change the momentum.

However, with the duration of the collision between the bullet and the bob being very small, the internal force exerted on the bullet by the bob and  the internal force exerted on the bob by the bullet are very much greater than the force exerted by the string tension and the gravitational attractive forces so the impulses exerted by the internal forces are very much greater than the impulses exerted by the external forces. 
The difference in the magnitudes of the internal and external impulses is so great that the external impulses can be neglected which is equivalent to saying that the external forces can be neglected.

For the bullet of mass $m$ the impulse on it during the collision would be $$\int _{\text{collision time}}(F_{\text{on bullet due to bob}}-mg) \, dt$$
and if $F_{\text{on bullet due to bob}}\gg mg$ this approximates to 
$$\int _{\text{collision time}}F_{\text{on bullet due to bob}} \, dt$$.

A similar analysis can be done for the bob.